# What happens to gravitational potential when the mass disappears?

Tags: classical-mechanics

This is from a section of my website.  Please tell me where it is wrong.

Consider two stationary gaseous planets, both made entirely of deutrium.

As the two planets are moved closer to each other gravitational potential energy will be lost and kinetic energy will be gained.  As the two planets move away from each other gravitational potential energy will be gained and kinetic energy will be lost.

Let's do work on the planets, increasing the gravitational potential energy of the planets, by moving them apart.  The increase in gravitational potential energy will be equivalent to the amount work we did separating the planets.

Now, let's say that the deutrium of both planets began to fuse by the following equation:

> ```
>      deuterium atom + deuterium atom => helium atom + neutron + 3.27 MeV
> ```

(It is true that I didn't include the initial energy to start the fusion.  However, the above equation is properly balanced, so we do not have to consider the initial energy required.  That is, let us assume the initial energy to start the fusion is somehow supplied.)

Now, it is obvious that mass is being converted into energy.  Since the masses of both planets are decreasing, the gravitational potential energy between both planets will also decrease.  Thus, the work we did moving the planets apart (which is now graviational potential energy) will diminish and disappear. Thus, we have demonstrated that the Law of Conservation of Energy is wrong.

Some may say that the light energy from the fusion of the deuterium affects gravity.  But, what is the gravitational potential energy of that light, when light has no mass?  Nothing.

Let me recap:  First, we did work by moving the two planets apart.  Thus, we lost kinetic energy while the planets gained gravitational potential energy.  We then converted the mass of the planets into energy.  Thus, we lost mass and in the process we lost gravitational potential energy.  So, all-in-all, we lost energy.

Or, you can consider throwing a ball up.  As the ball is heading upward kinetic energy is being converted into gravitational potential energy.  The ball will reach a maximum height when it has a velocity of zero and a maximum gravitational potential energy.  When the ball has reached its maximum height let us convert the mass of the ball into energy.  I don't know how to do this, but nonetheless, it is within the realm of possibility.  By doing that, the mass will disappear and so the gravitational potential energy will disappear.  The light energy from the conversion of mass into energy does effect gravity but it does not have mass, and so it does not have gravitational potential energy.

One might oversimplify the above to say:  "What goes up does not *necessarily* come down."

I recognize that this argument could very well be wrong.  Perhaps there will never be a invention which can turn mass into its equivalent amount of energy without this gravitational potential being realized.

Also, when one turns the ball, above, into light energy, do we consider its gravitational potential with *every* single particle (with mass) in the universe?  This is a tremendous gravitational potential!  Is it ever realized when the ball turns into light energy?

Radioactive materials create energy because they reduce in mass.  Thus, when a radioactive material ejects an alpha or beta particle along with heat then we should also have to account for the amount of gravitational potential lost by the mass which has turned into heat.  No where in the literature is there any accounting for this tremendous gravitational potential.

For instance, consider the gravitational potential of a 1 kg ball and the Andromeda Galaxy.  The 
gravitational potential energy is found using the integral of F*d, where F = G m1m2/d², and d is the distance to the Andromeda Galaxy, m1 is the mass of the ball, m2 is the mass of the Andromeda Galaxy, and G is the
gravitational constant.

> Now: d = 24E21m, m1 = 1kg, m2 = 3E42kg, G = 6.6E-11N(m/kg)²

So, the initial force on the ball and the Andromeda Galaxy is:

> ```
>      F = Gm1m2/r²
>        = 6.6E-11N(m/kg)² * 1kg * 3E42kg / (24E21m)²
>        = 6.6*3/24² E-11
>        = 0.03E-11N
>        = 3E-13N
> ```

The gravitational potential of the ball and the Andromeda Galaxy is:

> ```
>              F*d = G m1m2/x² dx, with x going from 1m to 24E21m:
>                  = 6.6E-11N(m/kg)² * 1kg * 3E42kg * dx / x²
>                  = 19.8E31Nm² * dx / x²
>                  = 19.8E31Nm² (-1/x), x goes from 1m to 24E21m
>                  = 19.8E31J (-1/(24E21)+1)
>                  = -19.8E31J (24E21-1)/(24E21)
>                  = -19.8E31J
> ```

So, when this ball disappears into light energy, what happens to the 19.8E31 J of gravitational potential this ball has with the Andromeda Galaxy.  And then, this is only one galaxy out of 100 billion galaxies!  Where does this tremendous gravitational potential energy vanish to when the ball's mass vanishes?!  That GPE is around 19.8E42J!

Comment: The mass-energy doesn't disappear but it spreads out. Nobody ever promised that gravity actually binds systems eternally. That's not even the case in Newtonian gravity for many-body systems. None of this has anything to do with the conservation of energy, which is the direct consequence of time translation invariance and which may or may not hold (for other reasons).

Comment: @user38403 Can you please decide whether the planets are being pushed and having work done on them or are flying apart ballistically?  The mish mash of inconsistency between work and kinetic energy was giving me a headache the whole time I read your question.

Comment: the planets are moving away from each other "magically".  There is some force being applied to both planets which makes them accelerate very quickly to a speed v, and then the planets eventually stop, due to their mutual gravity, at which point v is zero.  Thus, the gained gravitational potential is 1/2mv^2

Comment: From wiki on Conservation of energy: "Energy can neither be created nor destroyed; rather, it transforms from one form to another."  Is gravitational potential energy an energy which we can apply that quotation to?  If so, what  exactly is the GPE transformed into?  Thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: Your comment that light has no GPE since it has no mass is simply wrong. However, in this case GPE is converted into escaping photons and neutrinos. Case closed.

Comment: Youalso seem confused about the relative importance of things. Nobody worries about the change of GPE of 8E9 J when you annihilate a kg in Andromeda, because you have just turned it into 9E16 J of energy. Same story for radioactive decay, nuclear fusion in stars etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, you say "Case closed." but I just want to be sure: Is the 19.8E42J "converted into escaping photons and neutrinos"?  If you claim so, then I can also say that the case is closed.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Light interacts with gravitational wells.  Relativity makes things far more complicated than in your model.  This will give a taste of why you are not correct:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift